# TwitterのシェアボタンのJavaScriptコードを理解したい

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
!function(d, s, id) {
}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

Twitterのシェアボタンのコードの一部です。

1. `function`の前にある`!`はどういう意味ですか。
2. 最後の`(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');`はどういう意味ですか。

また、これを`coffeescript`で書くとどうなりますか?

Answer (score 1):

1)否定ですね。関数の返値がtrueに解釈できるものをfalseにしfalseに解釈できるものをtrueにします。
　@quesera2 さんが指摘するように単に関数を評価するために使われていると思われます。

2)この部分は関数に引数として`document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs'`を与えて呼び出します。

[coffeescript版テスト](http://coffeescript.org/#try:!((d%2C%20s%2C%20id)-%3E)(document%2C%20'script'%2C%20'twitter-wjs')%3B)

Comment: 典型的な即時関数は関数部分を`()`で括るのですが、これはその亜種の書き方です。否定演算子を利用することで関数式を評価させているのです。

Comment: @quesera2 ああ、なるほど。ありがとうございます。

Comment: coffeescriptって使える環境じゃないのでわかりませんが、`!((d, s, id)->)(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');` ですかね。

Comment: 返値が単に捨てられ関数を実行するためだけであるならcoffeescriptで`!`は付ける必要はありません。